# Azure Storage in Commvault

Tags: azure-storage, commvault

I'm busy investigating the Azure storage options for Commvault, and I noticed the article specifying that you need to configure Azure storage as Hot even though it's configured in Commvault as Archive. Am I interpreting this correctly?

https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=91299.htm

That does inflate the cost of Azure storage considerably, and I'm battling to understand why this is. the only thing I can think is because of any early access fees that apply to Azure Archive storage?

Can anyone give me the nod on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "must be hot" note on that page is only for Commvault Cool metadata / Archive data and Archive only storage classes. It reads:

> Caution: The container must be created with the ‘Hot’ storage class in
>   Azure even if you plan to use the Cool/Archive (Combined Storage
>   Tiers) option. Additional cost will be incurred if the container is
>   not created as ‘Hot’ in Azure.

The Hot, Cool, and Hot/Archive classes have just the note:

> Note: Additional cost will be incurred if the container is created
>   using a different tier.

Presumably, Commvault would change the tier of the blob, otherwise why offer these different classes.

Any [tier change](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers#blob-level-tiering-billing) has read or write changes, and also early deletion fees apply when source tier is cool or archive.

Archive blobs must first be written as hot or cool first. Cool guarantees an early deletion fee if archived immediately, and has higher access fees than hot. So set hot at the account level if you use archive.

Comment: Thanks John, much appreciated.